# Running JAR - Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: intellij-idea, build, jar, exe, artifact

I cannot run my JAR file.
I tried java -jar machines.jar, still getting thew same error.
Tried from inside Intellij, again the same error. Please, i'm so desperate for a solution. I 'm just giving up.
I have Screenshots, pom file, that you might need.
Really, i'm working months on this, and now i just want to export it.
If i'm about to have such SILLY problems with Java, i'm thinking of moving to c++./
I feel ready on giving up on this and re-write it on c++. I'M THAT DESPERATE.

PATH:
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.4.11-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-11.0.4.11-hotspot\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\bin;

Tried with launcjer4j.
About 20 times tried to build within Intellij. Really, i 'm beginning to feel very nervous and angry. I am working months with this project, it's my first one, i CAN'T EXPORT IT!

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>Codey</groupId>
<artifactId>Machines</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <finalName>Main</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java/FX</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java/FXMach</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java/FXGlob</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>

    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jfoenix/jfoenix -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
        <artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--            JavaFX 12.0.2           -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-base -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-media -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Error: Could not find or load main class Main
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you mar `src/main/java` as a **resource** type in Maven configuration? Leave it as a **source** type and put MANIFEST.MF into a `resource/META-INF` directory.

Comment: Thank you for your response my friend. Do you believe that just this might be the fix? ..I will be able to try it in 4 hours - when i get back from work.

Comment: Nope. Does not fix anything